Which mta should we prefer for sending mails?
We want to be able to send e-mails using SMTP at certain planned time or after certain activities however we do not want to rely on any service such as gmail, amazon, sendgrid. Which MTA would you prefer for a creating mail server on linux for this purpose?
I also appreciate if there is any related links, guides.
